# How to init argparser by looping instead of invoking `add_argument` for every argument manually?

Tags: python, argparse, dry

When making a CLI with `argparser`, as soon as the number of arguments increase the code start to repeat itself significantly.

It can be seen with the [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#example) from the docs already:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

This is a basic example and it's good that it's written in such a way, however it is possible to see the duplication of `add_argument` calls. You can likely assume that for a more complex CLI that quickly becomes a problem. Here is a [real example](https://github.com/labgrid-project/labgrid/blob/master/labgrid/remote/client.py#L1257-L1542).

Is there a way to overcome this to make the initialization more compact but still readable? (Please no suggestions for alternative CLI frameworks)

**Update to clarify**

We are repeatedly calling the same function with different arguments one after the other. My gut feeling is there might be a way to group those arguments into a structure, and then execute `parser.add_argument` with combination of star/"double star" operators on a list containing the above mentioned structures.

[ArgumentParser.add_argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) has the following declaration:

```
ArgumentParser.add_argument(single positional argument, lots of optional keyword arguments)
```

I'm looking for a data structure together with the asterisk  operators which could be unpacked into `single positional argument, lots of optional keyword arguments`.

Comment: Other than the function name `parser.add_argument()`, there's nothing being repeated. What kind of improvement are you looking for?

Comment: If you have many parameters and you don't want to write all of them every time in the CLI you could add a single parameter `--params param_file.json` and use a json file that contains all the parameters... It easy to change and with only 1 param you get the same result.... It reads worse... but it works.

Comment: It is not a problem. You simply can move parsing code into a separate module or even package. Then in your main code just call ```from cli_parser import parse_args```. Something like that.

Comment: @hidden @barmar Perhaps the other way would be to look this from a perspective of summing all integers in a list. Would you then also argue that calling `add_to_sum()` manually for every element of the list is equally good as iterating through the list with a loop and writing `add_to_sum()` once? :)

Comment: You can write as many utility functions as is convenient.  `ipython` sets up its parser duplicating variables in a `config` file.

Comment: Some `argparse`  extensions, like `plac`, use introspection on function arguments (and their annotations) to construct `argparse` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think it violates DRY. We use the same function couple of times, but we don't repeat its code.

What's about your question in the comments about summing of integers in the list, you suggested to use the for cycle and call "add_to_sum" function once. But what's against applying it to the "add_argument"?

```py
ARGS = (
    (('-x', '--crossbar'), {'type': str}),
    (('-c', '--config'), {'type': str})
)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

for arg in ARGS:
    parser.add_argument(*arg[0], **arg[1])
```

Comment: Thanks @hidden. You're probably right that it doesn't violate DRY in the form defined in the "Pragmatic programmer" or wherever it was initially defined. I guess I don't know how to call a principle where it's better to "loop through a structure and write the function invocation once instead of writing it every time without a loop". It's still a bit about not repeating oneself :p